# Should both mysqld_safe and mysqld be running at the same time on startup?

Tags: linux, mysql, centos

On launching my CentOS VPS (setup by someone else), MySQL starts two processes on boot:

1. mysql : /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql
2. root: /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.

Is this normal / the correct way to setup MySQL (that root is running mysqld_safe?)

Thanks!

Comment: all the parameters like key_buffer_size need to be on mysqld or mysqld_safe?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, that's the way it's supposed to be. mysqld_safe spawns a mysql-user run daemon (mysqld).

Answer (score 0):

If you take a peek into the contents of `mysqld_safe` you'll find that it is merely a shell script wrapper for launching `mysqld`.

Comment: Oh,... if you look inside mysqld_safe it does quite a bit more than a mere wrapper.