# Is mysqld_safe supposed to run always?

Tags: mysql

In my server I noticed that I have mysqld and mysqld_safe processes running simultaneously. Is mysqld_safe supposed to run always, together with mysqld?

Comment: Found another question which answers mine. http://serverfault.com/q/70613/60058 TL'DR version: Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best that does. If you read the the code for mysqld_safe, there is basic startup initialization in the beginning and an indefinite loop at the bottom. Here is the pseudocode description of the Loop

Start the Loop

- run mysqld inside the loop
- once mysqld terminates, check for how terrmination occurred

  - if normally terminated, exit loop (such as `service mysql stop`)
  - if abnormally terminated on startup, exit loop (errmsg posted in error file)
  - if abnormally terminated otherwise, errmsg posted why mysqld died
- retry mysqld

End of Loop

This is an oversimplified description of what mysqld_safe does